# ExtJs : Multiple objects in a grid cell

Tags: javascript, extjs4

Oh Hi!

I've been using ExtJs lately to get data from a json and display it in a nice way. Extjs does a very good job.

But today I've encountered a problem to display some values.

My json comes from a collection of objects. Each object has got an object in it, as follow :

```
{"product":
    [{"saleReference":
        [{"attributes":{"idReference":"100"}},
        {"attributes":{"idReference":"101"}}]
    }]
}
```

There are multiple product, but right here it doesn't matter.

So, in my cell, the display result is : [object Object],[object Object],... and so on as I've got a dataIndex using saleReference directly, like :

```
dataIndex : 'saleReference'
```

I've tried to use 'saleReference.attributes.iReference' to get it, but it didn't work. I get a "obj.saleReference.attributes is undefined" error.

I've also tried to use "combobox" to display the collection of object, but didn't get any result.

If someone has already gotten this problem and solved it, I'm really interested in the solution.

Comment: what is your desired outcome? how would you want your data displayed?

Comment: Well at first I wanted to display it in a combobox, but just display the value separated by comas would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use renderer to format value. Eg:

```
renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
    return value[0].attributes.idReference;
}
```

See [API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/) for additional information.

Comment: Ok that woks perfectly, I didn't see anything that could help me on the API that's why I asked here.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
Or you can use template column:
```

If you have data like this acRole:[{role:'roleA'}, {role:'roleB'}]

```
this.tplLoop = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for="acRole" ">',
            '{role}<br/>',
            '</tpl>'
        );


        config.moreCols = [
            {
                xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                dataIndex: 'acRole',
                header: this.DIGITAL_SAFE_ROLE_USERS_COLUMN_HEADER_PREFIX,
                id: 'acRole',
                sortable: false,
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode,
                tpl: this.tplLoop,
                hidden: true
            },];
```